# Docker and Django: how to render templates in a right way

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I started with Docker and Django a little while ago and I have run into a problem.

I want to create an application in Django using Docker. I found this guide on the Docker website itself and followed the steps.

The problem occurs when I want to start using Django templates:

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /app/templates/sao_app/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/sao_app/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/sao_app/index.html (Source does not exist)
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app/
```

Here is the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Currently, my file structure looks like this

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
├── sao_app
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── sao_app
│   │       └── index.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── sao_project
    ├── asgi.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
    │   ├── settings.cpython-39.pyc
    │   ├── urls.cpython-39.pyc
    │   └── wsgi.cpython-39.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

my `sao_app/views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'sao_app/index.html')
```

My `TEMPLATES` section in `sao_project/settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

My hypothesis:

I believe that there is a problem in defining paths when creating my container. I just don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Please show us the [`TEMPLATES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#templates) section in your settings file.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Just updated my question with TEMPLATES section.

Comment: Does this run outside Docker in a Python virtual environment?

Comment: Try taking `'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/'templates']` out completely. I never use that setting since `'APP_DIRS': True` works so nicely out of the box.

Comment: I think you need to remove BASE_DIR /'templates' or add 'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/'sao_app/templates']

Comment: @DavidMaze same issue as well. Django rises TemplateDoesNotExist at /

Comment: @andrii_ufu, so this has nothing to do with Docker. It is likely a problem with your `TEMPLATES`. Have you tried taking `'DIRS'` out entirely as I suggested?

Comment: @Chris yes, sir. Just removed a 'DIRS' entry and nothing changed. Still showing "TemplateDoesNotExist at /"

Comment: @JailtonSilva, there's no reason to put an app name (presumably that's what `sao_app` is) into the `'DIRS'` section. Just let `'APP_DIRS'` do its job.

Comment: @andrii_ufu, and to be completely clear your `sao_app` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`? If it isn't you should have received a different, earlier error, but I want to make sure it's there.

Comment: `BASE_DIR/'templates'`  is wrong

Comment: @Chris Thank you. After putting "sao_app" in the list of installed apps, everything went as expected.

I think this could be the solution to the problem, because it is more generic.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @andrii_ufu. I have added an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `"APP_DIRS": True`, Django will automatically look in the `templates/` subdirectory of each of your installed apps (where your template lives).

Make sure your `sao_app` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Generally speaking, apps don't do anything until you have installed them this way.

Note that this has nothing to do with Docker.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to remember that when overriding a specific model in a Docker container, you must follow this file path format:

/templates/app_name/model_name/{file_you_want_to_extend_or_override}

Additionally, it is worth noting that if your model is named "MyModel", the Docker container will only render the template if it is spelled in all lowercase as "mymodel".

Answer (score 0):

This should locate all templates inside your apps:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```